# How to connect to 802.1X authentication automatically?

Tags: macos, mojave, server.app, profile-manager, 802.1x

Currently, we're implementing 802.1X authentication in the company, but having some trouble with getting an IP address when using some Macs (MacBook Pro).

So, I created a profile through Profiler Manager of macOS Server. After the profile installed, I was able to get an IP address by manually clicking "Connect".

**PS: We are using the EAP-TLS.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I have to manually click "Connect" to get an IP address, every time I disconnected the Mac from the LAN cable or reboot the Mac.

So my question is: Is there any way to trigger the 802.1X authentication to get an IP address automatically or is there is any way to click (without interaction or silently in the background, maybe command line or plist files?) the "Connect" button automatically once a user logs in?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Configurator will allow you to create a profile that will auto-authenticate 802.1x.

Here is some more info https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-mac/create-and-edit-configuration-profiles-pmd85719196/mac

This works on Sonoma as well.